# Create different thumbnail sizes by screen-width, or go with largest thumbnail size for largest screen size?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm building an application where I have a list view and a map view.  The list view has `image` and `info` sections, but I am having difficulty with the image scaling.

The images are images that users upload of themselves, their listings, etc.  I am using AWS Lambda + S3.  So, I have flexibility to modify the image scaling for thumbnails, potentially creating multiple dimension thumbnails.

How should I scale these images so they can be accessible for mobile/tablet, desktop, and large (2k+) displays?  Should I make 3 or more resolution scaled images from the image the user uploads, and then have some kind of `img-sm`, `img-md`, and `img-lg` differentiator?

Thanks

Comment: How could we help you without your codes? Please give some codes.

Comment: My question is a bit more general.  It isn't about the code, I'm able to create the resizing on my end, but I am asking rather if I should have 3 different sets of thumbnails for the 3 different display devices I am targeting, or go with one size.

Comment: It is your decision to set same scale or different. There is no rule for this. See the mobile view or others, If it is not what you want, then change it.

Comment: Thanks.  I was just curious because on some sites I frequent a lot, I see that they have multiple dimensions of the same images used in various settings.  For example, they have 100x100 and 200x200 images, and then for profile photo thumbnails on a post or something, it will use the 100x100, and use CSS to set it to like 50x50 or something.

Answer (score 0):

Use `img` tag with `srcset` attribute. 
More info: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/

Answer (score 0):

I won't recommend resizing by CSS. Because the large file is anyway being downloaded on the user's device and will take more time to load in comparison to a small resized image.

In the case of serving perfectly sized images, you have two popular approaches.

One approach is to create resized images in all dimensions that are required, as soon as the user upload the image.

Another approach is to just upload one single large image and then get the desired dimension by specifying height & width in the URL parameter. It has more benefit. This will allow you to change the layout of your application in future without much effort from your side. Otherwise, you would have to again re-upload the old images in new required dimensions.

You can check out [ImageKit.io](https://imagekit.io). It has all these features + optimization.